# What happens when an Azure push notification fails to send?

Tags: c#, azure-notificationhub

Is there any documentation on what the NotificationOutcome class state looks like on a failure?

```
NotificationOutcome result = await _hub.SendNotificationAsync(azureNotification, tags);
```

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationoutcome_properties.aspx) is pretty (completely) useless.

I'm guessing non-zero for `result.Failure` and `result.Success` means something went wrong (both seem to be 0 on a success) `result.State` is maybe more useful but there doesn't seem to be much documentation on this either

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the answer on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient.enabletestsend) page

> If the EnableTestSend property is set to false for a
>   NotificationHubClient object, all Send* methods return a
>   NotificationOutcome instance with State set to Enqueued, and no
>   additional information. If EnableTestSend is true, State will be set
>   to DetailedStateAvailable, and this class contains information about
>   how many notifications were successfully delivered. In case of
>   failures, it provides the specific outcome, in the same manner as the
>   notification hub telemetry.

That means that Success and Failure mean the number of succeeded and failed notifications and will exist only if EnableTestSend parameter was set to true on client creation.

Comment: Does it have something equivalent in Java based backend - https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-java-backend

Comment: @masT try asking directly in that repository by creating an issue