# Azure Notification Hub Outcome

Tags: .net, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I'm working with **Azure Notification Hub SDK** (1.0.9).
The azure documentation is not very rich. 
Can you please help with the question:

According Azure docs, method `SendDirectNotificationAsync` return `NotificationOutcome`. There are two `Int64` properties: `Success` and `Failure`. Docs says: it gets or sets the success/failure value of the outcome. **Can you tell what are those numbers for**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Success and Failure mean the number of succeeded and
>   failed notifications and will exist only if EnableTestSend parameter
>   was set to true on client creation.

[Click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30018643/5598926)